# Are child entities automatically tracked when added to a parent?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I want to know whether EF CodeFirst will automatically track "child" objects in the example below.

```
var db = MyDataContext();
var order = db.Orders.Find(orderId);
order.AddOrderLine("Fancy Product");
db.Commit();
```

Here are my (simplified) domain entities

```
public class OrderLine {
  public Guid OrderLineId { get; private set; }
  public Guid OrderId { get; private set; }
  public string Description { get; private set; }

  public OrderLine(Guid orderId, string description) {
    OrderLineId = Guid.NewGuid();
    OrderId = orderId;
    Description = description;
  }
}

public class Order : Aggregate {
  public Guid OrderId { get; private set; }
  public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; private set; }

  public void AddOrderLine(string description) {
    OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine(OrderId, description));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you get your `Order` from context and add the new `OrderLine`, `DbContext` will insert it to database calling `SaveChanges`. It will also track all changes to loaded `OrderLines`. The only exception can be deleting existing `OrderLine`. If your `OrderLine` has PK only `OrderLineId` removing `OrderLine` from `Order.OrderLines` collectin will not delete `OrderLine` in database but instead it will set its `OrderId` to null (= exception in your case). If both `OrderLineId` and `OrderId` are PK in your `OrderLine` entity removing `OrderLine` from `Order.OrderLines` will also delete `OrderLine` in database.

Comment: @jessegavin: Are you satisfied with the answer or do you need any clarification?